# ScalaJS IntelliJ won't recognize my library

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala.js, scalatags

I'm trying to use the Scalatags library, but IntelliJ won't acknowledge certain parts of the library. I have it in my build.sbt like so:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "scalatags" % "0.6.0"
```

In my source file, I'm importing the library like so:

```
import scalatags.JsDom.all._
```

which is exactly how it's shown in the docs here: http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#ScalaTags

But IntelliJ won't acknowledge JsDom as part of the scalatags library. If I use

```
import scalatags.Text.all._
```

there's no problem. But JsDom isn't recognized, and doesn't come up as a suggestion while typing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using %%% instead of %%.  %%% is the special signal to sbt that it's a js library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%` uses the JVM version of the library. You need to use the platform-dependent version with `%%%`, like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.6.0"
```

This will select the JS version of the library if your project is a Scala.js project, thereby providing JS-specific parts of the API, such as `scalatags.JsDom`.

Comment: That fixed it. I see now there are two Scalatags dependencies in docs with the one you showed listed under ScalaJS. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.